# Bootstrap table | Make responsive for small resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I found when I open my table on phone or tablet the "Table" created with bootstrap is not responsive.
Maybe I did something wrong, but I really don't understand...

Can somebody help me with this problem?

```
 <div class="well">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="results">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Užívateľ</th>
            <th>Dátum</th>
            <th>Účel</th>
            <th>Cena €</th>
            <th>Poznámka</th>
            <th>Financovanie</th>
            <th><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center">Doklad</span></div></th>
            <th width="36px"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr title="Posledná úprava: 3.8.2013 18:05"></tr>
            <td>Viktor Bako</td>
            <td>3.8.2013</td>
            <td>Šeky</td>
            <td>100.00</td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span4"></span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="btn-danger spanNas text-center">Neuhradené</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center"><span class='text-danger'>Nie</span></span></div></td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr title="Posledná úprava: 3.8.2013 17:15">
            <td>Peter Jar&#158;embovsk&#253;</td>
            <td>3.8.2013</td>
            <td>Šeky</td>
            <td>25.00</td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span4"></span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="btn-info spanNas text-center">Firemné</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center"><span class='text-danger'>Nie<span></span></div></td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr title="Posledná úprava: 3.8.2013 13:08">
            <td>Karol Hot&#225;r Hotar</td>
            <td>3.8.2013</td>
            <td>Šeky</td>
            <td>28.99</td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span4"></span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="btn-info spanNas text-center">Firemné</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center"><span class='text-danger'>Nie<span></span></div></td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr title="Posledná úprava: 3.8.2013 07:52">
            <td>Karol Hot&#225;r Hotar</td>
            <td>3.8.2013</td>
            <td>Šeky</td>
            <td>28.99</td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span4">Pau&#353;&#225;l</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="btn-info spanNas text-center">Firemné</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center"><span class='text-success'>Áno<span></span></div></td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr title="Posledná úprava: 2.8.2013 23:54">
            <td>Viktor Bako</td>
            <td>2.8.2013</td>
            <td>Stravné</td>
            <td>4.10</td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span4">obed</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="btn-info spanNas text-center">Firemné</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center"><span class='text-success'>Áno<span></span></div></td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr title="Posledná úprava: 3.8.2013 14:32">
            <td>Peter Jar&#158;embovsk&#253;</td>
            <td>1.8.2013</td>
            <td>Šeky</td>
            <td>35.00</td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span4">je to v poriadku parada</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="btn-success spanNas text-center">Uhradené</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="row"><span class="span1 text-center"><span class='text-success'>Áno<span></span></div></td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody></table></div><div class="row"><div class="well label-warning span4">Spolu: 222.08 €</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the CSS that was written for the table?

Comment: I don't have the css for this table.. i think is just created in bootstrap

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: tables are not responsive in bootstrap. bootstrap supports responsive layouts. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: I have the previous version

Comment: Bootstrap v3.0 has responsive tables and is released!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what you are after?

[Live view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/GXZSJ/show/)
[Edit view](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/GXZSJ/)

If it is, firstly double check you have the correct path to Bootstrap CSS. Also you have some [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fpanchroma%2FGXZSJ%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) which might cause problems on some devices.  For example at lines 17 & 18 you had

```
 <tr title="Posledná úprava: 3.8.2013 18:05"></tr> 
 <td> ...
```

which didn't look good

It looks to me like your table needs a little over 600px to display properly. If you need better results on small screens one option would be to use a jQuery responsive table plugin, [here's one](http://declanbright.xtreemhost.com/jquery-plugin-responsive-table) to get you started.

Good luck!